# Staying focussed - Any applications to monitor what windows are open, record the titles and then tell you what you spend you day doing?

Tags: software-recommendation, productivity

I am bad at procrastination. I'm always opening new tabs to check out HackerNews or something. So I've installed StayFocussed on Chromium, so that I can't view more than X minutes of certain sites.

Is there something like this for the Ubuntu Desktop? It would work with applications, not websites (obviously).

I would like an application that would monitor what windows I have open or visible, and limit me to only certain applications. Maybe give warnings if I spend to much time looking at IRC or something. Is there any applications for that?

Comment: I don't a specific app that covers your exact specifications but I think you can use Zeitgeist activity Journal to find out what you were using day, week etc...

Answer (score 1):

How about hamster-applet?
From the package description:
 Project Hamster helps you to keep track of how much time you spend on various
 activities during the day.  Whenever you move from one task to another, you
 change your current activity in the GNOME applet.
 .
 It can present graphical statistics of how long you have spent on each task,
 and may be useful for project management or keeping employee timesheets.

Comment: As far as I have been able to tell, Project Hamster requires you to add everything *yourself*. Though useful for certain situations, I don't think it would be what he is looking for since you don't tend to write down start times and end times when procrastinating.